# Class cluster with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, class-cluster

I'm trying to create a class cluster as subclass of `UIViewController` to accomplish some points:

**1.** Different behavior of the ViewController depending on actual iOS version

**2.** iOS version checks don't clutter up the code

**3.** Caller doesn't need to care

So far I got the classes `MyViewController`, `MyViewController_iOS7` and `MyViewController_Legacy`.

To create instances I call the method `myViewControllerWithStuff:(StuffClass*)stuff` which is implemented like:

```
+(id)myViewControllerWithStuff:(StuffClass*)stuff
{
    if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
    {
        return [[MyViewController_iOS7 alloc] initWithStuff:stuff];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[MyViewController_Legacy alloc] initWithStuff:stuff];
    }
}
```

The caller uses `myViewControllerWithStuff:`. After that the so created view controller gets pushed onto a `UINavigationController`'s navigation stack.

This nearly works as intended with one big downside: ARC doesn't dealloc the instance of `MyViewController_xxx` when it gets popped from the navigation stack. Doesn't matter which iOS version.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** -initWithStuff:

```
-(id)initWithStuff:(StuffClass*)stuff
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.stuff = stuff;
    }

    return self;
}
```

This method is also implemented in `MyViewController`. The differences kick in later (e.g. `viewDidLoad:`).

Comment: Do you have a strong reference to it somewhere else in the code? The class cluster stuff seems like a red herring. It shouldn’t be causing problems.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you might want to return `instancetype` instead of `id` in order to get better compile-time type safety checks (against the superclass, at least).

Comment: The caller has a local reference `MyViewController *viewCtrl = ...` in an `IBAction` method and also in `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` which gets passed to the navigation controller. But there is no property or instance variable for it.

Comment: What is in your `initWithStuff` method? I tried your code snippet in a basic Master Detail Application and the custom view controllers had been deallocated.

Comment: Are you sure ARC is enabled?

Comment: "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" is set to YES for debug and release. ARC is disabled for some classes with "-fno-objc-arc", but not for the class cluster.

Comment: Is ARC disabled for the customers of the class cluster?

Comment: By customer you mean the caller of `myViewControllerWithStuff:`? That is also ARC-enabled. If that's alright the way it is, I guess I have to do a deeper search than before :( I'll keep you updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Thanks for all your help, comments, answers, suggestions...

Of course there was another `strong` reference to the `MyViewController`-object. But it wasn't that obvious, because it was not a property or instance variable.

In `viewDidLoad` I did the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    [self saveState];
}];
```

This should prevent data loss in case the user sends the app to the background. Of course the block captures the needed parts of its environment. In this case it captured `self`. The block keeps `self` alive until it (the block) gets destroyed, which is the case when e.g. `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` gets called. But, bad luck, this call is placed in the `dealloc` method of `MyViewController` which won't get called as long as the block exists...

The fix is as follows:

```
__weak MyViewController *weakSelf = self;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    [weakSelf saveState];
}];
```

Now the block captures `weakSelf`. This way it can't keep the `MyViewController`-object alive and everything deallocs and works just fine.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you put back the strong reference to `self` and run the static analyzer, does it catch the retain cycle?

Comment: Nope, nothing. The block could be retained by the Notification Center. In that case we don't have a cycle, but the block would still block the `dealloc` ceremony ;)